# Wordpress site loading twice

Tags: wordpress

When the page loads for some of the pages on this site, it loads twice. It will start to load and then the page goes white and loads again. I'm not sure why. Here is an example.
https://www.stukent.com/media-planning-textbook/

Answer (score 1):

remove:

```
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
    n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
    document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

    fbq('init', '1526461917650425');
    fbq('track', "PageView");

    (function(a,s,y,n,c,h,i,d,e){s.className+=' '+y;h.start=1*new Date;
    h.end=i=function(){s.className=s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?'+y),'')};
    (a[n]=a[n]||[]).hide=h;setTimeout(function(){i();h.end=null},c);h.timeout=c;
    })(window,document.documentElement,'async-hide','dataLayer',4000,
    {'GTM-TDWRKJ4':true});


        </script>
```